# User-Agent in pdfkit for python

Tags: python, pdfkit

```
import pdfkit
user_agent = {'User-Agent':'my custom user agent'}
options = {
    'custom-header': user_agent,
    'custom-header-propagation':''
    }

pdfkit.from_url('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent','test.pdf', options=options)
```

I´m using pdfkit to make pdfs from an url. I want to set a custom user-agent string, but its not working.

I am still getting the wkhtmltopdf user-agent. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/53) on GitHub, you need to pass your custom header like this:

```
import pdfkit

options = {
    'custom-header': [('User-Agent', 'my custom user agent')],
}
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent','test.pdf', options=options)
```

Note the tuple instead of the dict used in your code sample.

Comment: The value of the "custom-header" key must be an array like is : [('User-Agent', 'my custom user agent')]